# Where to put Values on php SQL insert Statement

Tags: php, sql

```
    $sql2 ="INSERT INTO customer (customer_id,first_name,surname,address,delivery_address) 
    VALUES('$customer_id','$first_name','$surname','$address','$delivery')
    SELECT first_name 
    FROM customer WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = ".$first_name.") ";
```

I just need to know where to put my values , there seems to be an issue with it 
I want to only insert a new customer into the table if he does not already exist. 
I will search by let's say , name, address to make sure he is unique...

PS: It is just for a project I am doing, SQL injections and so on are not really an issue I need to worry about for now.

Comment: Use prepared/parameterized queries.  With this SQL, you will no doubt be hacked via SQL injection attacks.  Learn to use PDO or similar.

Comment: Yeah I'm building a PHP program using mysql.

Comment: You're best setting a column to UNIQUE to be 100% sure of not getting any duplicate entries, "then" do your insert.

Comment: Depending on your table/index structure, you may be able to use [Insert...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use variables for your values try it this way:

```
VALUES('".$customer_id."','".$first_name."','".$surname."','".$address."','".$delivery."')
```

Comment: try iy this way it might help

Comment: normaly variabels in a statement have to be between'$variable' or '".$variable."'